# Java Service Wrapper Executable Runnable Jar

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

WrapperAppJar
I am wrapping an executable runnable jar file as a window service. Based upon the tutorial on Tanuki software site I export my app from eclipse as an executable jar file and tried wrappig it into a windows service. My app runs smoothly from the CLI when I execute java -jar smpp-portal -port 90. However with the Wrapper service I am getting some errors.
This is my configuration file

```
#encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
#wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
#wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=../lib/smpp-portal.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-port

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
# wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Unity SMPP Server

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Ignore output from dumping the configuration to the console.  This is only needed by the TestWrapper sample application.)
wrapper.filter.trigger.999=wrapper.filter.trigger.*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.999=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.999=NONE
#  Ignore -verbose:class output to avoid false positives.
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=[Loaded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1000=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1001=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1001=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1001=The JVM has run out of memory.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Email Notifications. (Requires Professional Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Common Event Email settings.
#wrapper.event.default.email.debug=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.host=<SMTP_Host>
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.port=25
#wrapper.event.default.email.subject=[%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%:%WRAPPER_NAME%:%WRAPPER_EVENT_NAME%] Event Notification
#wrapper.event.default.email.sender=<Sender email>
#wrapper.event.default.email.recipient=<Recipient email>

# Configure the log attached to event emails.
#wrapper.event.default.email.attach_log=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.lines=50
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.format=LPTM
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.loglevel=INFO

# Enable specific event emails.
#wrapper.event.wrapper_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_prelaunch.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_started.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_deadlock.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stop.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stopped.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_failed_invocation.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_max_failed_invocations.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_kill.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_killed.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_unexpected_exit.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.wrapper_stop.email=TRUE

# Specify custom mail content
wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email.body=The JVM was restarted.\n\nPlease check on its status.\n

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=SmppServer

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=Unity SMPP Server

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=Unity SMPP Server

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START, DELAY_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

However I got the following error message:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.17
wrapper  |   Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
wrapper  |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
wrapper  |
wrapper  | --------------------------------------------------------------------
wrapper  | Thank you for your interest in the Java Service Wrapper.
wrapper  |
wrapper  | You are running with a full featured trial License Key which will
wrapper  | allow you to run or restart the Java Service Wrapper as many times
wrapper  | as you like.  Each invocation of the Wrapper will shutdown
wrapper  | automatically after 15 minutes.
wrapper  |
wrapper  | This limited trial License Key is useful for quick configuration
wrapper  | tests on various machines without the need to request a trial
wrapper  | license.  If more time is required, you can also immediately obtain
wrapper  | a one-month Free trial license:
wrapper  |   http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial
wrapper  |
wrapper  | The Java Service Wrapper requires a License Key to activate the
wrapper  | software.  License Keys can be purchased on the Java Service Wrapper
wrapper  | web site:
wrapper  |   http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
wrapper  |
wrapper  | This trial License Key in intended for testing and development and
wrapper  | should not be used as part of a production environment.
wrapper  | --------------------------------------------------------------------
wrapper  |
wrapper  |
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapper  | Command: "C:\Windows\system32\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Duser.language=en -Djava.library.path="../lib" -classpath "../lib/wrapper.jar" -Dwrapper.key="KEggEM-am9F0iQdg0DR2yCJvAaJoF1WU" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.
min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=7856 -Dwrapper.version="3.5.17-pro" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.arch="x86" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 -Dwrapper.lang.domain=wrapper -Dwrapper.lang.folder=.
./lang org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp ../lib/smpp-portal.jar -port
jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...
jvm 1    | Missing attributes for JarRsrcLoader in Manifest (Rsrc-Main-Class, Rsrc-Class-Path)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp:
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error: Encountered an error running main:
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:46)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp.run(WrapperJarApp.java:394)
jvm 1    | WrapperJarApp Error:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Tanukisoftware: Please can you assist me

Answer (score 3):

unhillbilly has a good point. But actually it's not the real reason for the error you are seeing. 
Basically the manifest file in your jar file appears incorrect.

When you created the jar file, you were probably exporting your project from eclipse as runnable jar and selected as library handling to package the required jar files into the generated jar...

So by doing this Eclipse is using the class [JarRsrcLoader](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/eclipse/eclipse-3.5.2/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.java.html).

This class is in fact the main class of your executable jar and not as you might thought your main class.

JarRsrcLoader requires 2 parameters being set in the manifest file: Rsrc-Main-Class and Rsrc-Class-Path.

Rsrc-Main-Class is the class name of your actual main class.

Rsrc-Class-Path is the class path (with all included jar files in the jar file) to launch your application.

Your manifest file appears to miss those 2 properties.

So you can resolve this by changing the way how you are exporting the jar file, for instance use "extract required libraries in jar". 
Another option would be to add the 2 missing properties into your META-INF/manifest.mf file.

Answer (score 0):

Is a value missing for the `port` option?   You say that your jar is run as:

```
 java -jar smpp-portal -port 90
```

However, the wrapper config doesn't seem to have the port number as an application parameter:

```
# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=../lib/smpp-portal.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-port
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other executable wrapper

- Launch4J - [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmooth/files/latest/download?source=files)
- JSmooth - [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmooth/files/latest/download?source=files)

Other options are also available :)